# Using google drive API from FLEX client

Tags: google-drive-api, dropbox

Did anybody managed to use Google drive / dropbox from FLEX client (Not AIR)?

Also, I think that crossdomain.xml doesn't exist on their servers.

Thanks,
Shay

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer about flex, but you can use CORS for most of the API (soon will be all).